# How to get ALL topics for telegram supergroup using TelegramAPI

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, py-telegram-bot-api

I need to get all topics for my telegram group using python3 and pyTelegramBotAPI library. How can I do it?

Thanks!

I can get topic ID during creating. But can't get all topics list. Or may be I dont understand how its works. https://pytba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/types.html#telebot.types.ForumTopic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible. The [Telegram Bot API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api) does include functionality to query the list of all existing topics.

Comment: I looked at the documentation and, unfortunately, I also did not find such functionality. Maybe there is a workaround?

Comment: There is nothing that can be done with the bot api - simple as that.

Comment: @CallMeStag so you are trying to say the API does NOT include this functionality?

Comment: Yes, that's what I.m saying. Feel free to click the link in my answer, which leads to Telegrams official Bot API documentation, including all available functionality.